# How to find corresponding color based on dataframe using Setnames

Tags: r, plot, colors, colorbrewer

I have the following data frame:

```
dat <- structure(list(TPR = c(0.081, 0.945, 0.953, 0.984, 0.956, 0.031
), FPR = c(0.081, 0.545, 0.606, 0.869, 0.636, 0.01), Classifier = structure(c(1L,
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L), .Label = c("Luck", "NN", "RF", "SVM"), class = "factor"),
    Mean_AUC = c(0.5, 0.91, 0.91, 0.91, 0.91, 0.764), Classifier_with_mean_AUC = c("Luck(0.500)",
    "RF(0.910)", "RF(0.910)", "RF(0.910)", "RF(0.910)", "SVM(0.764)"
    )), .Names = c("TPR", "FPR", "Classifier", "Mean_AUC", "Classifier_with_mean_AUC"
), row.names = c(309L, 155L, 161L, 187L, 164L, 2L), class = "data.frame")
```

It looks like this:

```
      TPR   FPR Classifier Mean_AUC Classifier_with_mean_AUC
309 0.081 0.081       Luck    0.500              Luck(0.500)
155 0.945 0.545         RF    0.910                RF(0.910)
161 0.953 0.606         RF    0.910                RF(0.910)
187 0.984 0.869         RF    0.910                RF(0.910)
164 0.956 0.636         RF    0.910                RF(0.910)
2   0.031 0.010        SVM    0.764               SVM(0.764)
```

What I want to do is to determine the corresponding color for `Classifier_with_mean_AUC`.

```
library(RColorBrewer)
colors = brewer.pal(7, "Dark2")[1:7]
colors<-setNames(colors[1:nlevels(dat$Classifier_with_mean_AUC)], levels(dat$Classifier_with_mean_AUC))
colors
```

At the end of that code it only produces one color `#1B9E77`, I expected it to produce 3 colors. How can do it correctly?

I expect it to produce something like this.

```
Luck(0.500)      RF(0.910)       SVM(0.764)
"#1B9E77"        "#D95F02"       "#7570B3"
```

Comment: what are you expecting `nlevels(dat$Classifier_with_mean_AUC)` to give? currently it gives 0

Comment: @SymbolixAU: I expect it to produce `4`

Comment: In that case, you either need to set your values to `factor`, or use `setNames(colors[1:NROW(unique(dat$Classifier_with_mean_AUC))], unique(dat$Classifier_with_mean_AUC))` for `char`

Comment: @SymbolixAU: I got error `Error: unexpected input in "setNames(colors[1:NROW(unique(dat$Classifier_with_mean_AUC))‚"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with `levels`, you need to be using factors. Currently your `Classifier_with_mean_AUC` is a character column.

```
library(RColorBrewer)
colors = brewer.pal(7, "Dark2")[1:7]

## using character values
setNames(colors[1:NROW(unique(dat$Classifier_with_mean_AUC))], unique(dat$Classifier_with_mean_AUC))
# Luck(0.500)   RF(0.910)  SVM(0.764) 
#  "#1B9E77"   "#D95F02"   "#7570B3" 

## to use levels, convert your column to factor
dat$Classifier_with_mean_AUC <- as.factor(dat$Classifier_with_mean_AUC)
setNames(colors[1:nlevels(dat$Classifier_with_mean_AUC)], levels(dat$Classifier_with_mean_AUC))
# Luck(0.500)   RF(0.910)  SVM(0.764) 
#  "#1B9E77"   "#D95F02"   "#7570B3"
```